# Order of an element

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

$\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)}$ is a field.

I need to find an element $a \in \mathbb{F}$ of order $p^n-1$

I know that $\mathbb{F}$ has order $2^3 = 8$ so $a$ must have order 7

ie,  $a^7 = 1$

However, I have been mindlessly trying polynomials to see if they have order 7, which as you can imagine lead to scome scary calculations.

Am a missing an important theorem?

Answer (score 2):

First, the elements of $\;\Bbb F\;$ are *not* polynomials but, if you want, residue classes of polynomials modulo the ideal $\;I:=\langle x^3+x+1\rangle\;$ .

Second, if we denote $\;w:=x+I\in\Bbb F\;$ , then in this field we have the rule $\;w^3=w+1\;$ (why?), so we can write down the elements of the field:

$$\Bbb F=\{0,\;1,\;w\;,w+1\;,w^2\;,w^2+w\;,w^2+w+1,\;w^2+1\}$$

with arithmetic modulo $\;2\;$ and the above rule $\;w^3=w+1\;$. So, for example, we have:

$$\begin{align*}&w\\&w^2\\&w^3=w+1\\&w^4=w\cdot w^3=w(w+1)=w^2+w\;,\;\;etc.\\\end{align*}$$

Of course, in this case there's no problem: **any** element in $\;\Bbb F^*\;$ which is different of $\;1\;$ is a generator of the field *and* of the multiplicative group, since the latter is of order $\;7\;$ , a prime (why?) .

Comment: Ok, brilliant.
I think I know why 7 being prime is important - the order of every element of F* must divide the order of the group, 7. So the only element of order 1 is 1 itself, therefore every other element must be of order 7, right?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how did you arrive at w^3 = w+1?

Comment: Is it because w^3+w+1 = 0, and so w^3 = -(w+1) = w+1 modulo 2?

Comment: Indeed so, @user136650 . Remember, $\;w:=x+I\in \Bbb F/I\;$